# Python & Cpp file not included in documentation

Tags: doxygen, ros

## Intro

I recently try to use Doxygen to document my ROS project. I didn't find a good way to create documentation for all my custom package "cleanly" with the rosdoc_lite package. In cleanly, I heard have a all the documentations linked in one big documentation (I hope that's clear enough).

Therefore, I try to generate a doc for all my ROS project with Doxygen. I have, right now, not a good idea how to structure my documentation, but I structure it as I learn Doxygen. I'm happy to have your advice if you want to share on a possible structure, or a way to use rosdoc_lite for all package.

## My Problem

My main problem is I can not achieve to have all my h/py file documented. The problem occurs in one specific location.

```
Include
├── RStatus
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Side.h #Documented
│   ├── State.h #Shown in file list but not documented
│   ├── State.py #Not shown in file list
└── Services
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── RobotServices.h #Documented
    ├── RobotServices.py #Documented
```

Each file has a @file, @brief and @author tag at the head of the file.

In addition, I tried to change the @file tag to @package in the State.py file. Doxygen create a empty namespace.

I'm stuck on this problem, and I don't know how to handle it.

If you want any more information, ask me!

Thx for your time !

Comment: Can you please attach a, small, self contained example  that allows us to reproduce the problem?
Please also specify the doxygen version used.

Comment: Answers go in the **Answer** box, not as edits to the question. This is not a forum, do not treat it as one.

Answer (score 0):

As I try to make a small example of my problem, I found that I had 2 files with the same name located in two different package (#noob). I google it and I found that Doxygen can not distinguish automatically two files in two package. I did as ask in Doxygen docs (see here: http://www.doxygen.nl/commands.html#cmdfile) and everything works. (Each @file tag need to be unique. If needed, add dirpath to the file.)

In conclusion : My bad. -_-